# How to disable next js source maps only in production environment whereas enable in other non prod?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, production-environment, source-maps

Here is my next.config.js, here i have added the productionBrowserSourcemaps:true, to generate the /static/chunks/statusCheck-6tghgrrtf.map.js.

When i add the flag its generating the original code in all environments. But i want to hide the original and .map code in production alone. How to do it ?

next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
restrictStrictMode:true,
productionBrowserSourceMaps:true,
basePath:'/example',
images:{
 loader:"imgix",
 path:""
},
env:{ 
 NEXT_PUBLIC_BUILD_VERSION: 1.0.0
}
}
}
```